# C: Weird behaviour between client and server

Tags: c, ubuntu, websocket, server

I'm writing a server-client program in C. The client sends a command to the server in the form of 5 bytes: the first byte is an operation, and the next 4 bytes are the key to do the operation on.

The server looks something like this:

```
int nowread, key;
while(1)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int alreadyread = 0;
    do
    {
        nowread = read(socket,buffer+alreadyread,5-alreadyread);
        alreadyread += nowread;
    }
    while((nowread > 0) && (5-alreadyread > 0));

    if(nowread == -1 || nowread == 0)
    {
        printf("Error reading from client socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    key = (((int)buffer[1])<<24 | ((int)buffer[2])<< 16 | ((int)buffer[3]) << 8 | ((int)buffer[4]) << 0);

    printf("%d, key from server \n",key); // just for debugging


//DO COMMAND
```

I've been testing the program by having the client send 10 commands:

```
 op: 1, num: 645110
 op: 2, num: 419811
 op: 0, num: 115300
 op: 2, num: 792023
 op: 2, num: 146624
 op: 1, num: 842346
 op: 1, num: 450778
 op: 0, num: 550046
 op: 1, num: 284186
 op: 2, num: 691858
```

And I get from the server:

```
-10, key from server 
-29, key from server 
-15772, key from server 
-41, key from server 
-64, key from server 
-9622, key from server 
-38, key from server 
-98, key from server 
284186, key from server 
-110, key from server
```

As you can see, only one key matches, which is very strange (either they should all match or none). I am 100% sure this is serverside and not a problem with the client. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This is the code that sends the data

```
    uint32_t net_num = htonl(num);
    int nsent = 0;
    while (nsent < 4)
    {
        rc = write(sockfd,&net_num + nsent, 4 - nsent);
        if (rc <= 0)
        {
            printf("error! write() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

        nsent += rc;
    }

    if (rc <= 0)
        break;
```

Comment: How do you *send* the data?

Comment: It's very important that you show the code that sends the data. You may be running into endianness problems or other subtle issues.

Comment: You send four bytes, but receive five, do you send a byte before the number you show us?

Comment: The fact that most of your keys come out negative make me think you are running into a signedness problem with the way in which you are translating the key into a value.  Try changing the type of `buffer` to array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: Also, you'll need to be a lot more careful if you want to be able to transfer negative keys, because any arithmetic operation on signed integer values whose mathematical result is not in the range representable in the target type produces undefined behavior.

Comment: John, you're the man ! Works perfectly now!

Comment: Yet another broken `do / while` loop: `alreadyread` should not be updated if `nowread < 0`.

Comment: What makes you think `(5-alreadyread > 0)` is more readable than `alreadyread < 5`?

Comment: the check for a read() error needs to be immediately after the read() statement, NOT outside the loop.   And if a read() fails, the posted code is doing nothing to correct the problem that caused the failure.

Comment: regarding this line: 'printf("%d, key from server \n",key);'  The key is from the client, not the server.

Comment: regarding this line: '&net_num + nsent'  'net_num' is declared as in int, so any addition to '&net_num' will advance the address some multiple of the width of an 'int'.   (I.E. by 4 bytes for each count in nsent.  so this will not send the successive bytes of net_num.    1) there is no reason to not send all 4 bytes in one send() call.  2) to send byte by byte, net_num needs to be part of a union of 4 char and an int and the send() parameter should be referencing the value via the char array.

Answer (score 1):

The `char` type is signed on your system, so the byte values are sign-extended when you convert them to `int` as you are computing the `key` value on the server side. The explicit casts are not needed, and the result would be identical without them.

You must make `buffer` an array of `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char buffer[1024];
```

The client code is erroneous too, it only works if `nsent` is `0`. If for some improbable reason `write` only writes between `1` and `3` bytes, you will try and transmit bytes from memory beyond the end of the `net_num` variable, invoking undefined behaviour:

write(sockfd, &net_num + nsent, 4 - nsent);

You should do this instead:

```
write(sockfd, (unsigned char*)&net_num + nsent, 4 - nsent);
```

Or better, for consistency with the server code:

```
char buffer[5];
ssize_t rc, nsent;

buffer[0] = code;
buffer[1] = (num >> 24) & 255;
buffer[2] = (num >> 16) & 255;
buffer[3] = (num >>  8) & 255;
buffer[4] = (num >>  0) & 255;

for (nsent = 0; nsent < 5; nsent += rc) {
    rc = write(sockfd, buffer + nsent, 5 - nsent);
    if (rc <= 0) {
        printf("error! write() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        break;
    }
}

if (rc <= 0)
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are processing the buffer in wrong direction. You also need to convert it back from network bytes. ntohl ( ) does that.

Like this:

```
uint32_t key;
uint32_t result;

key = ( uint32_t )(( buffer [ 1 ] << 0 )  |
                   ( buffer [ 2 ] << 8 )  |
                   ( buffer [ 3 ] << 16 ) |
                   ( buffer [ 4 ] << 24 ));

result = ntohl ( key );
```

Comment: I think you are mistaken: the OP **does** process the buffer in network to get the value directly.  From his own data, one transmission is correct: `284186, key from server` which would not be the case if the byte order was erroneous. The errors come from using a `char` array instead of `unsigned char`.  Your method has the same problem, plus it does not work on a big-endian platform: you should have read `key` this way: `key = *(uint32_t*)(buf + 1);` but the address would need to be properly aligned. The OPs method is much simpler. He should use it in the client code as well, for consistency.